# Can I use if statements in one-line cmd scripts?

Tags: cmd

Imagine I want to do:

```
IF condition (do something) & (do something irrespective of the condition)
```

in a one-line batch script. It seems that after the IF statement, everything else is interpreted as part of the if block, and therefore the code afterwards isn't getting executed if the condition evaluates to false.

Comment: Have you tried putting the first command in brackets? `(IF condition (do something)) & (do something irrespective of the condition)`

Comment: yeah this worked thanks. Can you make it an answer so i can approve it

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your syntax. You adapted

```
IF <condition> <something>
<something else>

// ---------------
//  OUTPUT where <condition> 
//
//  TRUE:  <something>
//         <something else>
//  
//  FALSE: <something else>
```

into

```
IF <condition> <something> & <something else>

// ---------------
//  OUTPUT where  <condition> 
//
//  TRUE:  <something> & <something else>
//
//  FALSE:
```

The multi-line example has a line break to communicate the end of the `if` statement which has been replaced by the `&`.  To have `IF <condition> <something>` interpreted separately from `<something else>`, in the absence of a line break you could enclose your `if` statement within brackets causing it to be executed in its entirety prior to the `&`:

```
(IF <condition> <something>) & <something else>

// ---------------
//  OUTPUT where <condition> 
//
//  TRUE:  <something> & <something else>
//  
//  FALSE: <something else>
```